# g.drawString not drawing Game Over when the Two Squares Collide

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a virtual tag with squares. For now, I'm focusing on getting the game to say game over and close a second later when the player who's it catches the other player. However, when the two squares collide, the program writes nothing to the screen.

I know that the if statement where the g.drawString is called works because made it here is outputted to the console twice so I'm confused as to why g.drawString doesn't work.

```
package com.Arman;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Virtual_Tag {

    static int x1 = 0;
    static int y1 = 0;
    static Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    static int height = (int) dimension.getHeight();
    static int width = (int) dimension.getWidth();
    static int sWidth = (int) (Math.round(100 * width / 1366.0));
    static int sHeight = (int) (Math.round(100 * height / 768.0));
    static int x2 = width - sWidth;
    static int y2 = height - sHeight;
    static myGraphicsPanel graphics = new myGraphicsPanel();
    static boolean[] move = new boolean[8];
    static int xSpeed1;
    static int ySpeed1;
    static int xSpeed2;
    static int ySpeed2;
    static boolean xcol, ycol;
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
        text1.addKeyListener(new keyListener());
        left.add(text1);
        JTextField text2 = new JTextField();
        text2.addKeyListener(new keyListener());
        JPanel right = new JPanel();
        right.add(text2);
        frame.add(left);
        frame.add(right);
        frame.add(graphics);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        while (!xcol || !ycol) {
            keyListener.move();
            x1 += xSpeed1;
            x2 += xSpeed2;
            y1 += ySpeed1;
            y2 += ySpeed2;
            int s1 = x1;
            int e1 = x1 + sWidth;
            int s2 = x2;
            int e2 = x2 + sWidth;
            xcol = (s1 <= s2 && s2 <= e1) || (s1 <= e2 && e2 <= e1);
            s1 = y1;
            e1 = y1 + sHeight;
            s2 = y2;
            e2 = y2 + sHeight;
            ycol = (s1 <= s2 && s2 <= e1) || (s1 <= e2 && e2 <= e1);
            Thread.sleep(10);
            frame.repaint();
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    static class keyListener extends KeyAdapter {
        private HashSet<Integer> pressed = new HashSet<>();
        private final int[] KEYS = {KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN,
            KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, KeyEvent.VK_UP};

        public static void move() {
            ySpeed1 = 0;
            xSpeed1 = 0;
            ySpeed2 = 0;
            xSpeed2 = 0;
            if (move[0]) ySpeed1 -= 10;
            if (move[1]) xSpeed1 -= 10;
            if (move[2]) xSpeed1 += 10;
            if (move[3]) ySpeed1 += 10;
            if (move[4]) ySpeed2 += 10;
            if (move[5]) xSpeed2 -= 10;
            if (move[6]) xSpeed2 += 10;
            if (move[7]) ySpeed2 -= 10;
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            pressed.add(e.getKeyCode());
            for (int f : pressed) {
                boolean found = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8 && !found; i++) {
                    if (f == KEYS[i]) {
                        move[i] = true;
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8 && !found; i++) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KEYS[i]) {
                    move[i] = false;
                    found = true;
               }
           }
            pressed.remove(e.getKeyCode());
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // not used
        }
    }

    static class myGraphicsPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(x1, y1, 100, 100);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(x2, y2, 100, 100);
            if (xcol && ycol) {
                g.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 36));
                g.drawString("Game Over!", 0, 0);
                System.out.println("Made it here");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your printing coordinates to move the string right and down.  Try `200,200`.

Also, you should do the following:

- Get rid of your static statements.
- Then move your code in main into the method `start()`.  You can then invoke your
  program by doing the following:

```java
  new VirtualTag().start();
```

Normally you should start your program in main as follows:

```java
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new Virtual_Tag().start());
```

But in this case that won't work because you would be continuously looping in the `Event Dispatch Thread` and nothing would get painted.

- Check out painting and such in the
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Where do I put my static statements and how do I access the start method?

Comment: You don't need any static statements.  The start method can be right after `main()`   Something like `public void start()`.  I do this regularly to get out of the `static context` of `main`.